# want to move my price before image using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to move my `price` class div before the `image`. For that, I have tried jquery code but no luck. I have a list of products so can't just use simple class reference. Because this code shows all prices in one place. I want to show each image have separate prices above that.but in my case it's showing all the prices in one place. Thanks

Mhy code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){
       jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        var i =1;
        $( "div.product-item" ).each(function( index ) {
             // console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );            
        $(this ).closest(".product-item-img").insertBefore( ".product-item-img" );
        i++;
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HMTL Code :

```
<div class="items-group">
                            <div class="products grid">
                <div class="item product-item">
                                        <div class="product-item-info">
                        <div class="product-item-img">

                            <a href="https://www.example.com/mens/short-sleeve/kuhl-mens-short-sleeve-airspeed-ss.html" class="product photo product-item-photo">

                                                                    <img class="lazy lazy-blur product-image-photo lazy-loaded" src="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/c7587e3bc9758535f28022fdb134c42e/7/1/7194_airspeed_ss_slate_front_1_style_zoom_3.jpg" alt="Airspeed SS" style="display: block;">
                                
                                                                
                            </a>

                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                            
                        </div> <!-- end: product-item-img -->
                        <div class="product details product-item-details">

                                                            <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                    <a class="product-item-link" title="Airspeed SS" href="https://www.example.com/mens/short-sleeve/kuhl-mens-short-sleeve-airspeed-ss.html">
                                        Airspeed SS                                    </a>
                                </strong>
                            
                                                                                        
                                                            <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="16031" data-price-box="product-id-16031">

<span class="normal-price">
    

<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label">As low as</span>
        <span id="product-price-16031" data-price-amount="52.5" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">$52.50</span></span>
        </span>
</span>

    <span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">
        

<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label">Regular Price</span>
        <span id="old-price-16031" data-price-amount="75" data-price-type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">$75.00</span></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
                        (-30.00%)    </span>

</div>                            
                            
                        </div> <!-- end: product-item-details -->
                    </div> <!-- end: product-item-info -->
                </div>
            </div>  

                
                
                            <div class="products grid">
                <div class="item product-item">
                                        <div class="product-item-info">
                        <div class="product-item-img">

                            <a href="https://www.example.com/mens/long-sleeve/kuhl-mens-long-sleeve-alloy.html" class="product photo product-item-photo">

                                                                    <img class="lazy lazy-blur product-image-photo lazy-loaded" src="https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/c7587e3bc9758535f28022fdb134c42e/3/1/3118_m_alloy_cosmos_lifestyle_style_zoom_1.jpg" alt="Alloy" style="display: block;">
                                
                                                                
                            </a>

                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                            
                        </div> <!-- end: product-item-img -->
                        <div class="product details product-item-details">

                                                            <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                    <a class="product-item-link" title="Alloy" href="https://www.example.com/mens/long-sleeve/kuhl-mens-long-sleeve-alloy.html">
                                        Alloy                                    </a>
                                </strong>
                            
                                                                                        
                                                            <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="14640" data-price-box="product-id-14640">

<span class="normal-price">
    

<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label">As low as</span>
        <span id="product-price-14640" data-price-amount="59.5" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">$59.50</span></span>
        </span>
</span>

    <span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">
        

<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label">Regular Price</span>
        <span id="old-price-14640" data-price-amount="85" data-price-type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">$85.00</span></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="price">
                        (-30.00%)    </span>

</div>                            
                            
                        </div> <!-- end: product-item-details -->
                    </div> <!-- end: product-item-info -->
                </div>
            </div>  

                                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML part as well please ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have added HTML code.But this code repeats just changes the image and other product details.

Comment: You have multiple `price` classes you want to move `all` of them of just the one with span => `-30%` ?

Comment: Yes but there are other price classes under top div. I want to just move the price that directly comes under the `price-box` class like `.price-box > .price`.if you see the HTML you will find the price class also exists for `price-wrapper` too.

Comment: So only want to move `-30%` - correct ?

Comment: Yes only that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` looks up the tree, you want `find()` to look inside and you need to isolate the specific image within the item also

Try something like:

```
 $( "div.product-item" ).each(function( index ) {         
    const $img = $(this).find(".product-item-img" )            
    $(this).find(".price").insertBefore($img );
 });
```

Comment: @Itay Yup... copied the selectors without even looking at them

Comment: The above code moves all the prices classes top. I just want to move the specific price class.you can see my comments on top for detail.

Comment: Scale down the html to only show what is relevant and so it is formatted. Not really clear what you need

Comment: got solution by changing class like this : `$(this).find(".price-box  > .price").insertBefore($img );`